# Angular change detection, when calling a function from template

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-changedetection

I have just called a function from a template and inside that I am simply returning true or false;

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-awrmsl?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Check the console of above link project, so array has 7 items but in console I can see twice logs. (
i have updated this question and stackblitz link)
i have images and i want on error img tag should not be there so i called the same function twice from template 
whats correct ways to implement this type of logic ?
**i need if error is there in image than no image tag should be there**

**Please check console logs**.

I have not changed any property - what might be happening here?

(I tried different answers in a search engine search still not getting the exact point).

Comment: What exactly would you like to know? As a basic rule, calling a function from your template is not a good idea.

Comment: Yes can you give a example why calling a function is not a happy case from template , sometimes it runs as we expect and sometimes it runs more than expected no. of times.
i have updated the code in stack-blitz link that what i was trying initially

Answer (score 1):

In angular, change detection is done by zone.js. Which figures out what part of the UI need to be re-rendered.

It will see your method `checkimage`, since it can't predict the value the method it will execute it. Hence you get multiple logs in the console.

Depending on the code inside the `checkimage` method it can cause performance issues. 
Rule of thumb: Don't call functions from the template.

You can change the code simply

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="id.sr">
  ff {{i}}
  {{  id.sr }}
</ng-container>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have updated the question , can you please check that out and suggest a solution  and also check latest code in that link as i am trying to call the function (error) part of that image too.

Comment: @LogicBlower What's your actual question here ?

Comment: please open the code and see console , it will show a value around 49 ,  i just want a solution that code (function call from template) should not run that many times. ? 
hope this time you understanding what i am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

**ngDoCheck** is `lifecycle hook` provided by `angular`.This method is used to detect and act upon changes that Angular can't or won't detect on its own.

This method runs after the **ngOnInit** once and also after each `change detection cycle`.

In the development mode , angular runs the extra change detection cycle initially.

In the production, you would only see one log in your case.

[More here](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have updated the question , can you please check that out and suggest a solution  and also check latest code in that link